# How to push the update information for visualstudiogallery?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I upload a VSPackage to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/, and when I create a new version VSPackage, how to make visual studio which has installed my VSPackage to update the new version VSPackage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating the `VSIX` package containing an updated version of your extension, you need to increase the version number in the package manifest (either do it via the `VSIX` designer, or change the `Version`-attribute of the `PackageManifest/Metadata/Identity` element via the XML editor). Otherwise the gallery won´t recognize the new package as an update.

Upload the package again (verify and save all changes); you should immediatly see the new version in Visual Studio´s extensions dialog.